# How to import java.beans package from java kernel, not from Android SDK?

Tags: java, android-studio, import

In my Android app I need to import `BeanInfo` class (and something else) from  `java.beans`pacakge. However, statement

```
import java,beans.BeanInfo
```

raises error `cannot find symbol`. Now I see that there is other package `java.beans` provided by Android SDK which has one interface and four classes but does not include `BeanInfo`. So, the question: is it possible to tell in `import` statement to point to `java.beans` package in java kernel, not from Android SDK?

Comment: I think you are referring to SDKs not kernels?

Comment: @magicmn, I think so. The statement is `import java.beans.BeanInfo`. Is it possible to qualify 'java.beans' to take it from kernel, not from SDK?